# Can I restrict google geocoder results by cities and towns?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

There are [component restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder) for the google geocoding api.

> admininstrativeArea, country, locality, postalCode, route

can I use any of these to filter by city and town?
So that I don't get back a country or state?

Something like

```js
this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
this.geocoder.geocode({
      address: this.registerForm.get('city').value,
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'US',
        locality // not sure here
      }
    },
    (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {}
    }
```

I can do it with google maps autocomplate!

```js
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.element, {
  types: ['(cities)']
});
```

Comment: locality filter is for cities and towns, but note that this filter is not strict, it just a bias to search address within locality. The actual result might be outside. Also, geocoding typically returns only one result (best-match), it is not like autocomplete service. If your intention is getting list of cities from geocoding service, it won't work.

Comment: My intent is to fetch just one result, but limit it to a country,  like I'm doing and by a city and/or town. I don't want the user, who enters text into a input, to be able to fetch a result as a State or Country. This is for a dating site and I'm trying to get the closest approximate location (city/town) without having the user enter in an exact address!!

Comment: If I can use locality, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Not sure if it works in all situations, but something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality%3AHouston%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY` seems to return city 'Houston, TX, USA'.

Comment: this is the url, I need an example using the API programmaticly

Answer (score 3):

Geocoding API's **[component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering)** actually behaves differently from the Places API -- **[Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types)**.

**Component filtering** lets you return addresses restricted to a specific area. Take for example, you search for "High St Hasting" with component restriction to `country: 'GB'`, the request will return the closest address match within the country "United Kingdom". The returned address may be of a type street address, neigborhood, country or other types.

**Places APIs place types** on the other hand, lets you return addresses that matches the given type. For example, you want to search for addresses of type "establishment" only.

I understand this feature is what matches your use-case in which you wanted to restict results to be of type cities or towns only. This feature is not currently supported by the Geocoding API.

As a workaround, you can use Places Autocomplete and bias the autocomplete results to favor an approximate location or area as stated in this **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)**. Your user can then select the correct location from the autocomplete suggestions.

```
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};
```

Place Autocomplete is also recommended if you search for ambiguous (incomplete) addresses, like when responding to user input. More details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices).

Hope this helps!